# Unable to connect to any of the specified MySQL hosts error when adding migration

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

So I'm doing a school exercise and I have to use Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools version 6.0.11 specifically. but every time I use the add-migration Initial command like the exercise says I have to, I get this error(these are all console lines starting with the command)

```
PM> add-migration Initial
Build started...
Build succeeded.
The Entity Framework tools version '6.0.11' is older than that of the runtime '7.0.2'. Update the tools for the latest features and bug fixes. See https://aka.ms/AAc1fbw for more information.
MySqlConnector.MySqlException (0x80004005): Unable to connect to any of the specified MySQL hosts.
   at MySqlConnector.Core.ServerSession.OpenTcpSocketAsync(ConnectionSettings cs, ILoadBalancer loadBalancer, Activity activity, IOBehavior ioBehavior, CancellationToken cancellationToken) in /_/src/MySqlConnector/Core/ServerSession.cs:line 1146
   at MySqlConnector.Core.ServerSession.ConnectAsync(ConnectionSettings cs, MySqlConnection connection, Int32 startTickCount, ILoadBalancer loadBalancer, Activity activity, IOBehavior ioBehavior, CancellationToken cancellationToken) in /_/src/MySqlConnector/Core/ServerSession.cs:line 438
   at MySqlConnector.Core.ConnectionPool.ConnectSessionAsync(MySqlConnection connection, String logMessage, Int32 startTickCount, Activity activity, IOBehavior ioBehavior, CancellationToken cancellationToken) in /_/src/MySqlConnector/Core/ConnectionPool.cs:line 403
   at MySqlConnector.Core.ConnectionPool.ConnectSessionAsync(MySqlConnection connection, String logMessage, Int32 startTickCount, Activity activity, IOBehavior ioBehavior, CancellationToken cancellationToken) in /_/src/MySqlConnector/Core/ConnectionPool.cs:line 408
   at MySqlConnector.Core.ConnectionPool.GetSessionAsync(MySqlConnection connection, Int32 startTickCount, Activity activity, IOBehavior ioBehavior, CancellationToken cancellationToken) in /_/src/MySqlConnector/Core/ConnectionPool.cs:line 98
   at MySqlConnector.Core.ConnectionPool.GetSessionAsync(MySqlConnection connection, Int32 startTickCount, Activity activity, IOBehavior ioBehavior, CancellationToken cancellationToken) in /_/src/MySqlConnector/Core/ConnectionPool.cs:line 128
   at MySqlConnector.MySqlConnection.CreateSessionAsync(ConnectionPool pool, Int32 startTickCount, Activity activity, Nullable`1 ioBehavior, CancellationToken cancellationToken) in /_/src/MySqlConnector/MySqlConnection.cs:line 929
   at MySqlConnector.MySqlConnection.OpenAsync(Nullable`1 ioBehavior, CancellationToken cancellationToken) in /_/src/MySqlConnector/MySqlConnection.cs:line 423
   at MySqlConnector.MySqlConnection.Open() in /_/src/MySqlConnector/MySqlConnection.cs:line 382
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ServerVersion.AutoDetect(String connectionString)
   at EFSamurai.SamuraiContext.OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder) in E:\School\WebServices\EFSamurai\EFSamurai\SamuraiContext.cs:line 14
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext.get_ContextServices()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext.get_InternalServiceProvider()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext.Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure.IInfrastructure<System.IServiceProvider>.get_Instance()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure.Internal.InfrastructureExtensions.GetService[TService](IInfrastructure`1 accessor)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure.AccessorExtensions.GetService[TService](IInfrastructure`1 accessor)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.Internal.DbContextOperations.CreateContext(Func`1 factory)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.Internal.DbContextOperations.CreateContext(String contextType)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.Internal.MigrationsOperations.AddMigration(String name, String outputDir, String contextType, String namespace)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.AddMigrationImpl(String name, String outputDir, String contextType, String namespace)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.AddMigration.<>c__DisplayClass0_0.<.ctor>b__0()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.OperationBase.<>c__DisplayClass3_0`1.<Execute>b__0()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.OperationBase.Execute(Action action)
Unable to connect to any of the specified MySQL hosts.
PM>
```

And this is the class using the Microsoft EntityFrameworkCore

```
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

namespace EFSamurai
{
    public class SamuraiContext : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<Samurai> Samurais {get; set;}
        public DbSet<Quote> Quotes { get; set;}
        public DbSet<Battle> Battles { get; set;}

        protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
        {
            var connectionString = "server = localhost; port = 3310; database = samurai-db; user=databanken; password=databanken";
            optionsBuilder.UseMySql(connectionString, ServerVersion.AutoDetect(connectionString));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: According to the error message, it just asked you to upgrade the nuget package to the latest version. Pls correct me if I misunderstood your issue, thank you in advance

Comment: could you pls remove the space inside the `connectionString`?

Comment: I removed all the spaces in connectionString and the problem remains

Comment: `Server=localhost;Port=3310;Database=samurai-db;User=databanken;Password=databanken"` Could you pls take a try with this?

Comment: I have tried this and the error remains the same

Comment: `Server=localhost;Port=3310;Database=samurai-db;Uid=databanken;Pwd=databanken;` and could you pls try this one?

Comment: This has not fixed the issue

Comment: `"Server=127.0.0.1;Database=samurai-db;Uid=databanken;Pwd=databanken;` and about this one? By the way, have you confirmed to connect to your database via a tool like MySQL Workbench？ just like you know, you could got a plenty of answers about your error message and the error message indicating a wrong connection string, so we'd better to make sure the connection string(keywords and value) is correct.

Answer (score 0):

You should first address the incompatibility between versions to see whether this resolves the issue.

The error says: "The Entity Framework tools version '6.0.11' is older than that of the runtime '7.0.2'"

Check your .csproj file.
Within this file you will see the list of dependencies used by your project (e.g. shown below)
[.csproj file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wDoIN.png)
Ensure the Entity Framework versions align.

If different go to Manage Nuget Packages and update their versions.